# What is the meaning of "Falcon Friday"?

Tags: meaning, american-english, terminology, north-american-english

The term Falcon Friday was found on [deviantArt Twitter](https://twitter.com/DeviantArt/status/1251290200795308034) and later found constantly used in academic domain, like in universities, what is the meaning of Falcon Friday when an university management use the term?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Falcon Fridays are opportunities for prospective students to visit a university and get an introduction to student life. The description for Bowling Green University is typical:

> BGSU’s Falcon Friday is an all-day, on-campus program, which offers an in-depth preview of college life at Bowling Green State University. Admitted seniors and their guests will have the opportunity to meet with admissions staff and students, explore academic facilities, tour the campus, and investigate possibilities for financial aid and scholarships.